# Uncaught TypeError: 'length' of null in jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want done `each` for json in following js code but i have error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null` and it don't work, what do i do?

json code:

```
[
   {
      "type_bad":"5"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"5"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"14"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"6"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"13"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"3"
   },
   {
      "type_bad":"8"
   }
]
```

my js code:

```
$('.TypeRoom').live("change", function (e) {
    val = 'id_units=' + id + 'type_room=' + type_room;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'get_unitsTB',
        data: val,
        cache: false,
        success: function (units) {
            $.each(units, function (index, val) {
                alert(val.type_bad);
            });
        },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It means `units` is `null`, look at the actual response in network tab of google chrome developer tools

Comment: You can also try: `success: function (units) { console.log(units); }` to be sure that your units is actually what you expect.